# How can I measure the pressure from my strain gauge?

Tags: voltage, wheatstone-bridge, strain-gage

I bought [a strain gauge from RS components](http://ph.rs-online.com/web/p/strain-gauges/0632124/), and I want to find out how can I get the pressure from the measured voltage on the strain gauge. I managed to the Wheatstone bridge and supply it with a voltage as Vex.

Based on [this document](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/3639/en/), the manufacturer will provide the conversion formula but on [the PDF manual](http://docs-asia.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/0077/0900766b80077de6.pdf) here is what I only found. Can someone help me or supply any reference on how can I compute the pressure?

Comment: A strain gauge will change its resistance based on physical deformation. The amount of force (or pressure) that makes that deformation depends entirely on the material it is bonded to.

Comment: It can only be calibrated when you've constructed your pressure gauge (bonded the strain gauge to a deforming disk etc.). You'll need to amplify the change in voltage (using a suitable amplifier) and see what outputs you get for a given (known) pressure.

Comment: Temperature compensation is important with a sensor like this.  Maxim Integrated's MAX1458 (an older part but still available I think) used a constant-current source (instead of a constant-voltage source) to drive the Wheatstone bridge, then inferred the temperature from the common-mode voltage. Calibration requires applying known pressures at known temperatures, then fitting a curve that approximates the physical input that corresponds to that output. In production, each individual sensor must be calibrated because of manufacturing variances.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to calibrate it yourself.  Put some known stresses on it and see what it does.  I used to work in industrial automation, and every one of the scales had to be calibrated in-place when empty and with at least one test weight before it would even be close to accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use microcontroller for example AVR ATMEGA 16 and then use ADC(Analog to digital converter) pins and then you measure voltage at your minimum pressure and call it 0
and max pressure 255 then you have 256 degree of pressure you can display on LCD.
(sorry for my bad english)